# How to cast implicit or automatically in java

Tags: java, casting

I have some trouble with casting attributes "automatically".

```
public abstract class MyType<T> {
    public abstract T getValue(String content);
}

public class MyString extends MyType<String> {
    @Override
    public String getValue(String content) {
        return String.valueOf(content);
    }
}

public class MyInteger extends MyType<Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer getValue(String content) {
        return Integer.valueOf(content);
    }
}

public class User {
    private String _name;
    private int _id;

    public void setName(String name) {
        _name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return _name;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        _id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return _id;
    }
}

public class MainTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<MyType> myTypes = new ArrayList<MyType>();
        myTypes.add(new MyString());
        myTypes.add(new MyInteger());

        User user = new User();

        for (MyType myType : myTypes) {
            try {
                user.setName((String) myType.getValue("foobar")); // getValue always returns an Object that I have to parse
                user.setId((Integer) myType.getValue("42")); // getValue always returns an Object that I have to parse
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind that this is only an abstract example of my problem.

How can I replace the castings? I need something like this:

```
user.setName((user.getName().getClass()) myType.getValue("foobar"));
```

Unfortunately eclipse tells me that this is wrong `The method getValue(String) is undefined for the type Class<capture#3-of ? extends String>`

I will not cast explicity. I will cast more implicity/automatically.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that the `myTypes` list is declared as a `List<MyType>`, which uses the [raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/139010) `MyType` instead of a particular parameterization of `MyType` in the list. [This is generally discouraged, warned against, bad practice, etc.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)

Ordinarily you'd declare the list like `List<MyType<String>>` or `List<MyType<Integer>>`. That would enable you to get elements out without having to cast. However, this is problematic because you want to be able to mix `MyType<String>` and `MyType<Integer>` in the *same* list. Again, this is generally not recommended, and is a [code smell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2279121/139010).

So you *could* declare a `List<MyType<?>>` instead, which is better than `List<MyType>`, but not by much. The only correct conclusion is that the design is inherently flawed: don't try to mix heterogeneous types in collections.*

---

> The class MyType was just an abstract example. Actually my question was how I can cast: `user.setName((user.getName().getClass()) object);` if object is Object object = "foobar";

Regardless, the problem is still fundamentally that you're using raw types in the list. It seems like you might be better off using something that maintains the type parameterization, such as a `Map<Class<T>, MyType<T>>` instead of a `List<MyType>`.

Consider applying [the strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) here.

---

<sub>*Expert mode: unless there is a sensible common supertype which you can use as an upper bound.</sub>

Comment: The class MyType was just an abstract example. Actually my question was how I can cast: user.setName((user.getName().getClass()) object); if object is Object object = "foobar";

Answer (score 3):

I agree 100% with [Matt Ball's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15042302/839646). A simple, quick solution, though maybe not the ideal one, is to remove the abstractness from MyType and add the ability to get the value as a specific type. You'll find this kind of pattern in [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) in the standard library, among other places:

```
public class MyType {
    private String content;
    MyType(String content) { this.content = content }
    public String getStringValue() { return content; }
    public Integer getIntValue() { return Integer.parseInt(content); }
}
```

Comment: Like I mentioned above, it was just an abstract example. The real problem/question was the casting => How I can cast: user.setName((user.getName().getClass()) object); if object is Object object = "foobar";

Comment: You can't for all the same reasons that Matt listed in his answer. You don't have the necessary type information. The only thing you could do here is [use reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html), which is almost always the wrong solution outside of infrastructure-ish code.